# How to force Dt[ ] to recognize dependencies

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to differentiate a function `f[]` for which I don't have a specific expression.

`f[]` depends on `x` and `y` and has parameters k1 and k2 in it.

`x` and `y` depend on `t`,and not on `k1` nor `k2`.

So when I use the total derivation operator `Dt[f, t]`, only `x` and `y` should be differentiated.

But how can I say Mathematica that k1 and k2 are constant, without assigning values to them?

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
Dt[f[x[t], y[t], k1, k2], t, Constants -> {k1, k2}]

(* Derivative[1][y][t]*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][f][x[t], y[t], k1, k2] + 
 Derivative[1][x][t]*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][f][x[t], y[t], k1, k2] *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Also,

```
SetAttributes[{k1, k2}, Constant]
Dt[Sin[k1 x + k2 y]]
(*
-> Cos[k1 x + k2 y] (k1 Dt[x] + k2 Dt[y])
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

In more general cases when `k1` and `k2`  depend on certain variables ( they are not constants nevertheless we may assume their total derivatives vanish) we can make use of [`TagSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSet.html?q=TagSet&lang=en) (`/:`)  :

```
k1 /: Dt[k1, t] = 0;  k2 /: Dt[k2, t] = 0;
Dt[ f[ x, y, k1, k2], t]
```

[image]

Instead of playnig with `TagSet`, sometimes a more flexible way would be `Refine` ( similarly `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`) with appropriate assumptions (i.e. vanishing total derivatives), e.g. :

```
Refine[ Dt[ f[x, y, k1, k2], t], { Dt[k1, t] == 0, Dt[k2, t] == 0}]
```