# VariationalD giving the wrong solution?

Tags: differential-equations, packages, symbolic

EDIT:  As pointed out in the comments, `VariationalD` gives a variational derivative (which I don't want), not a derivative with respect to a function (i.e. $\frac{df[x]}{dlog_e(x)}$ as a simple example - this is what I thought it did the first time I read the description).  Is it even possible in Mathematica to take the derivative of a function with respect to another function?  I know you can use the chain rule to rewrite, using the example just above, $\frac{df[x]}{dlog_e(x)}=x\frac{df[x]}{dx}$.  In my case the equivalent would be much more cumbersome and I want to be able to change the function w.r.t. which I'm differentiating.  Is it possible to do this in Mathematica?
_

I am using the `` VariationalMethods` `` package, specifically the `VariationalD` command.  I am trying to take the derivative of one (complicated) function fitted to experimental data with respect to another (complicated) function.

First I wanted to make sure that the command does what I wanted.  So I inputted the example given in `VariationalD`'s "Examples" section:

```
 VariationalD[y[x] Sqrt[y'[x]], y[x], x]
```

This gives a result of 
$$
\frac{d}{dy[x]}(y[x] \cdot y'[x]^{1/2})=\frac{2 y'[x]^2+y[x] y''[x]}{4 y'[x]^{3/2}}.
$$

Trying to reproduce this by hand I started with the product rule:

$$
\frac{d}{dy[x]}(y[x] \cdot y'[x]^{1/2})=y[x]\frac{d}{dy[x]}y'[x]^{1/2}+y'[x]^{1/2}\frac{d}{dy[x]}y[x]
$$
The second term is just

$$
y'[x]^{1/2}\frac{d}{dy[x]}y[x]=y'[x]^{1/2}.
$$

The first term, you use the chain rule on:

$$
y[x]\frac{d}{dy[x]}y'[x]^{1/2}=y[x]\frac{1}{2}y'[x]^{-1/2}\frac{d}{dy[x]}y'[x]
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dy[x]}y'[x]=\frac{dx}{dy[x]}\frac{d}{dx}y'[x]=(\frac{dy[x]}{dx})^{-1}y''[x]=\frac{y''[x]}{y'[x]}.
$$

Putting all of that together:

$$
\frac{d}{dy[x]}(y[x] \cdot y'[x]^{1/2})=y'[x]^{1/2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{y[x]y''[x]}{y'[x]^{3/2}}.
$$

Simplifying:

$$
\frac{d}{dy[x]}(y[x] \cdot y'[x]^{1/2})=\frac{2 y'[x]^2+y[x]y''[x]}{2 y'[x]^{3/2}},
$$

which is identical to the solution given by `VariationalD` except for a factor of 2.  So I assumed it was a mistake I made somewhere (and it might be) and tried comparing every step I made when doing it by hand with the corresponding step in `VariationalD`.  Eventually I discovered one difference in the step

```
 VariationalD[Sqrt[y'[x]], y[x], x]
```

which gives an answer of $\frac{y''[x]}{4y'[x]^{3/2}}$, a factor of 2 different than when I do it.  I'm still not sure where the factor of 2 in the $y'[x]^{1/2}\frac{d}{dy[x]}y[x]$ step comes from.

I kept messing around with it and found that

```
 VariationalD[y'[x],y[x],x]=0
```

which can't be right.  For example, if $y[x]=x^2$ and $y'[x]=2 x$,

$$
\frac{dy'[x]}{dy[x]}=\frac{d(2x)}{dx^2}=2(\frac{dx^2}{dx})^{-1}=2(2x)^{-1}=\frac{1}{x}.
$$

So why is `VariationalD` giving a zero answer?  It's even weirder because $\frac{dy'[x]}{dy[x]}$ comes up when you perform the original differentiation by hand as well.  It can't be zero there either or the first term would vanish and the answer would just be $y'[x]^{1/2}$.

So am I making a stupid mistake in my differentiation?  Even if so, why is `VariationalD` giving zero for the derivative with respect to a function of its derivative?

I've spent about an hour searching for anything relevant online, and...nothing.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:  I've been looking at the description of `VariationalD` more closely and now I'm not sure it does what I think it does, i.e.

```
 VariationalD[f[x],g[x],x]
```

gives $\frac{df[x]}{dg[x]}$ as output.  Is this correct?  Looking at the description it now seems to me that it would give $f[x]\frac{df[x]}{dg[x]}$.  But if that's the case then the output for my original expression is still wrong.

Comment: Do you mean convolution or ordinary multiplication when you write $*$ in your formulae? Also, are your $y[x]$ itself a functional since you used bracket instead of parenthesis?

Comment: @Silvia ordinary multiplication is the only one that makes sense.

Comment: @rcollyer Well, even though, I expect people compose their *TeXified* formulae meeting the common notation rules more..

Comment: @Silvia exchanged `*` for `\cdot`.

Comment: Yeah, "*" means multiplication, not sure why I wrote it that way.  y[x] is a function of x.  EDIT:  @rcollyer was going to change it but you beat me to it.

Comment: `VariationalD[y'[x],y[x],x]=0` because `y[x]` does not appear explicitly in the function that you are functionally differentiating w.r.t. `y[x]` - i.e. the functions `y[x]` and `y'[x]` can be independently varied. An example of this is described at [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Example).

Comment: @JohnHyatt Can you write the full form of the functional being derivated (_variationally_ speaking)?

Comment: @Stephen Luttrell The point of that example is that f[x] is unknown and you're trying to find it by varying...right.  So it *is* true that VariationalD doesn't do what I want.

Comment: If you functionally vary $f(x)$ (but not $f^\prime (x)$) at $x=a$, giving
$f(x) \longrightarrow f(x) + \delta(x-a)$ and
$f^\prime(x) \longrightarrow f^\prime(x) + \frac{d}{dx} \delta(x-a)$, then
integrate $x$ over an interval that includes $x=a$, you obtain
$\int f(x) \; dx \longrightarrow \int (f(x) + \delta(x-a)) \; dx = \int f(x) \, dx + 1$
but
$\int f^\prime(x) \; dx \longrightarrow \int f^\prime(x) \; dx + 0$ (integration by parts).
So functionally differentiating $f(x)$ does not functionally differentiate $f^\prime(x)$ once you integrate around the location where you are differentiating.

Comment: @Stephen Luttrell The issue is that I had misunderstood what VariationalD does; it gives the variational/functional derivative, and I wanted the non-functional derivative.  Unfortunately I still haven't found a way to do that in Mathematica outside of some special cases...I'll make a new Question focusing on that more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `VariationalD[y'[x],y[x],x]` indeed equals to zero.

You should not mistake [**functional derivative**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) with **ordinary derivative**, where in the former case $y'$ is usually considered an **independent variable** to $y$. so functional $\mathrm{d} y'/\mathrm{d} y=0$ is just like an ordinary $\mathrm{d} a/\mathrm{d} b=0$.

The same reason you can't write something like this in calculus of variations

$$\frac{\partial J[x,y,y']}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial J[x,y,y']}{\partial x}\,\text{,}$$

just like you can't write this in ordinary calculus:

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}\,\text{.}$$

Comment: Yeah, I realized that when I was re-reading the description of ``VariationalD`` again a few minutes ago.  I didn't catch the "variational" part, so what you're saying is exactly correct.  That said, is there another function that does what I want?  (I edited the top of the post to explain that more clearly - basically I want the ordinary derivative, not the functional one.)

Comment: @JohnHyatt I think you may check [`Dt`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10113/17), using it along with self-defined substitution rules.

Comment: I glanced at it briefly and am not sure if it will work, but I will give it a try tomorrow.  Thanks.